# Updating Table values after Button Event

Tags: java, swt

In my SWT-GUI, I have a `Table` with 3 columns and the rows will get updated from the data received from serial port event.

```
btnFetchRow.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if(myCommNew.serialDataExist()) {
                try {
                    final TableItem newRow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                    while(tblIndex<myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().size()) {
                        System.out.println("tblIndex Value:" + tblIndex);
                        System.out.println("Recvd Data Value:" + myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd());
                        newRow.setText(0, Integer.toString(tblIndex));
                        newRow.setText(1, getCurrentTime());
                        newRow.setText(2,myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().get(tblIndex));
                        System.out.println("The Value Recvd is :" + myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().get(tblIndex));
                        tblIndex++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception excWhile) {
                    System.out.println("Error in creating row");
                    System.err.println(excWhile.toString());
                    excWhile.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Everything is OK, if there is only one data in `ArrayList`(getSerialDataRecvd) BUT if there is multiple data in `ArrayList` then only last value (recent value) is updated in the `Table`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only create one new `TableItem`. You need to create one for each element in the `ArrayList`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().size(); i++)
{
    TableItem newRow = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    newRow.setText(0, Integer.toString(i));
    newRow.setText(1, getCurrentTime());
    newRow.setText(2, myCommNew.getSerialDataRecvd().get(i));
}
```

Comment: But my While loop is also doing the same thing. Also, when i moved the " final tableitem...." before 'try { code' then everything works  ok. Why??

Comment: The `new TableItem()` bit **has** to go into the loop (`for` or `while` does not matter). Otherwise you're just reusing the same item (row) instead of creating a new one for each of your elements.